# How to store large json data in application

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift

I have a long JSON data and I tried to download it through alamofire but it takes a long time to be downloaded.

My data is static and not changing frequently , So I was wondering How should I store that JSON inside the local storage so the user doesn't have to download the data at all .

How and where should I store that json data?

Comment: You can create a file in the application bundle with some name (eg: YourData.json) and read the contents of this file into Dictionary or Array.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr On new file window, what type of file should I choose ??

Comment: You could break that json into smalled pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file in the application bundle by select the directory and `->New File` then select `Other -> Empty`

[image]

now select a name for the file for `eg:YourData.json`,

[image]

then read the contents of this file with extension `json` to a Dictionary or Array

Comment: I find out that it's about 2 mb of json data.It's a list of states and provinces and i want to display them inside a UIPickerView with two components. Do you think it's a good way?I think there is an other way which is getting data for the second components after the user select the first one , This way it's a lot less data.What's the best way to handle that ?Thanks

Comment: in my opinion, if your app size is not too large already, go with the above solution of adding file in bundle. So that there is no need to call an API and also the data can be load faster.